# display error when get content from HTML using Dom

Tags: php, html

when i get content from this link using dom: 
[link here](http://blogviet.com.vn/blog-radio/blog-radio-329-hen-gap-em-o-verona/5797)

i have get this content is html as follows :

```
<div align="justify"> â€œâ€¦VÃ  em muá»‘n biáº¿t, nÆ¡i trÃ¡i tim váº«n nhá»› thÆ°Æ¡ng Ã¢m tháº§m bao lÃ¢u nay /Sáº½ mang Ä‘áº¿n cho mÃ¬nh Æ°á»›c mÆ¡ vá» háº¡nh phÃºc áº¥y /Hay lÃ  ná»—i xÃ³t xa, cÃ³ hay /Ráº±ng tÃ¬nh yÃªu em luÃ´n bao la /Rá»“i sáº½ tá»›i má»™t ngÃ y anh chá»£t nháº­n ra , tÃ¬nh ta nhÆ° Ä‘Ã³a hoa Ä‘á»£i khi náº¯ng mai /Khi Ä‘Ã´i mÃ´i láº¡i ráº¡ng rá»¡ , tÃ¬nh ta cháº³ng phai nhÃ²aâ€¦â€â€“ giai Ä‘iá»‡u ngá»t ngÃ o cá»§a má»™t ca khÃºc vang lÃªn trong chÆ°Æ¡ng trÃ¬nh radio Ä‘ang phÃ¡t sÃ³ng lÃ m cÃ´ chá»£t cháº¡nh lÃ²ng. Má»™t cáº£m giÃ¡c vá»«a quen vá»«a láº¡ nhen lÃªn nÆ¡i trÃ¡i tim. CÃ´ cá»‘ gáº¯ng lá»¥c láº¡i trÃ­ nhá»› cá»§a mÃ¬nh: 30 giÃ¢y! 1 phÃºt! 2 phÃºt! Chá»£t, máº¯t cÃ´ thoÃ¡ng buá»“n, cáº£m xÃºc trong trÃ¡i tim cÃ´ nhÆ° vá»¡ Ã²a khi táº¥t cáº£ nhÆ° má»™t cuá»‘n phim cháº¡y cháº­m trong trÃ­ nhá»› cÃ¹ng má»› cáº£m xÃºc há»—n Ä‘á»™n: DÃ²ng thá»i gian trá»Ÿ vá» trong cuá»‘n phim lÃ  nhá»¯ng ká»‰ niá»‡m cÃ¹ng anh â€“ chÃ ng sÄ© quan háº£i quÃ¢n. </div>
```

although this link content as follows :

```
 <div align="justify">1. Em không đẹp như các cô bạn gái trước đây của tôi. Em cũng không dịu dàng và nhìn tôi bằng ánh mắt trìu mến như họ. Em còn có một nhóc con đã ba tuổi, thằng bé dễ thương, kháu khỉnh và có đôi mắt buồn giống hệt mẹ. Em như một bông hoa dại cô độc, từng cánh hoa đơn trắng muốt, nhụy hoa vàng mềm mại, thân dài mảnh mai với những chiếc lá thanh mảnh, run rẩy nở trong gió nhưng không bao giờ cong gãy. Còn tôi, với đôi tay luôn được bao bọc trong lồng kính, lại tùy tiện ngắt hoa, không biết rằng trên đó có gai, cũng không hề biết rằng nó sẽ làm cho trái tim mình ứa máu. Đã hơn một lần tôi thổ lộ lòng mình với em nhưng đều nhận được ánh mắt lạnh lùng và lời từ chối phũ phàng:</div>
```

i know there is error format here ,but i cant fix it. how can i fix this in php ?.

here is my code :

```
$link_mp3=$linkTemp.HadlingLink($html2->find('object#jwplayer param [name=flashvars]',0)->value);
//echo $link_mp3.'<br/>';

$arrayContents=$html2->find('div[align=justify]');
//var_dump($content);
$contents='';
foreach ($arrayContents as $content){
    $contents=$contents.$content->outertext;
}
echo $contents;
```

when i change a litle code :

```
echo utf8_decode($contents);
```

it show : Nh? cô nàng ??ng ??nh, ??t át, ?m m?c kiêu k? ??ng gi?a anh chàng mùa ?ông l?nh lùng và anh chàng mùa h? ?m áp.

up date :

i fixed my probleam as follows : add

```
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "UTF-8", // handle all encodings
```

when get html using curl . here is function

```
 static function get_web_page($url)

    {


        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "UTF-8", // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "spider", // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 200, // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 200, // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
        );

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $header['errno'] = $err;
        $header['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
        $header['content'] = $content;
        return $header;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: yes. '$link_mp3=$linkTemp.HadlingLink($html2->find('object#jwplayer param [name=flashvars]',0)->value);
 //echo $link_mp3.'<br/>';

 $arrayContents=$html2->find('div[align=justify]');
 //var_dump($content);
 $contents='';
 foreach ($arrayContents as $content){
  $contents=$contents.$content->outertext;
 }
 echo $contents;'

Comment: Can you post it on the question ? It's hard to read here.

Comment: i just get content link top. but error  string

Comment: Do you declare encoding in the output header?

Comment: Can you show the part where the content is loaded with (for example) `file_get_html` or `str_get_html`? I'm interested to see how this issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

use following 'meta' tag in your html page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```